# An elaboration of a step in an example.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, fermat-numbers

A part of the example is given below:

> **Example 9.7.** Let us turn to a quite different application of these ideas. At an earlier stage, it was observed that if $F_n = 2^{2^n} + 1$, $n > 1$, is a prime, then $2$ is not a primitive root of $F_n$. We now possess the means to show that the integer $3$ serves as a primitive root of any prime of this type.
>
> As a first step in this direction, note that any $F_n$ is of the form $12 k + 5$. A simple induction argument confirms that $4^m \equiv 4 \pmod {12}$ for $m = 1, 2, \ldots$; hence, we must have
>
> $$F_n = 2^{2^n} + 1 = 2^{2 m} + 1 = 4^m + 1 \equiv 5 \pmod {12}$$

But I do not understand why $2^{2^{n}} = 2^{2m}$? could anyone explain this for me please?

Is the above mentioned $F_{n}$ is Fermat numbers? if so why the $n$ starts from 2 here?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You don't understand why $2^n$ is even when $n>1$?

Comment: Please edit your post to include your efforts.   Can you compute $F_1$?  Is it a prime?  Is $2$ a primitive root $\pmod {F_1}$?   If you can answer those questions, you will see why $n=1$ was excluded from the example.

Comment: yes I can compute $F_{1}$ .... but the author mentioned $n > 1$@lulu

Comment: My question is why $2^{2^{n}} = 2^{2m}$? @lulu

Comment: Right, so $2^n$ is even.  As to the $n=1$ question, you asked why it was excluded,  My comment points to the reason for that.

Comment: even when $ n=1$, we have that $2^n$ is even@lulu

Comment: I don't understand at all.  You asked " why the  starts from 2 here?"  Right?  I assumed you were asking why the example stated $n>1$, excluding $n=1$.  If you meant something else, please edit your post to ask your question more clearly.

Comment: you are understanding me correctly@lulu

Comment: $2^{2^1} + 1 = 5$, and $2$ is a primitive root of $5$.

Comment: And I gave you an answer, or rather I gave you a set of (extremely simple) steps which should lead you to an answer.

Comment: I am discussing your answer with you so that I convince myself with it @lulu

Comment: Please follow the steps I wrote down.  Well, I note that another user has already carried out all the steps I had indicated.

Comment: @IsaacSaffold  exactly ...... so $F_{1}$ is prime at 1

Comment: In the definition of Fermat numbers later in the book $n$ starts from 0.

Comment: Are you concluding that $F_{1}$ is prime because $2$ is one of its primitive roots? And regarding your next comment, why shouldn't $n$ start from $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I do not understand why $2^{2^{n}} = 2^{2m}$?

At this point in the text, the author has defined $m$ as $2^{n-1}$. (The author hasn't written this definition explicitly; presumably, they assumed that the reader would be able to figure it out easily.) Since $m = 2^{n-1}$,

$$2^{2^{n}} = 2^{(2 \cdot 2^{n-1})} = 2^{2 m}.$$

> Is the above mentioned $F_{n}$ is Fermat numbers? if so why the $n$ starts from 2 here?

Yes, $F_n$ is the Fermat numbers here. The author writes that for $n > 1$, if $F_n$ is prime, then $2$ is not a primitive root of $F_n$. Here, $n$ must be greater than $1$ because $2$ *is* a primitive root of $F_1$ (which is $5$).

> what about the $m$ beside the congruence at the third line from below? are there 2 different m's?

Yes, those are two different $m$'s. The author could just as well have used a different letter for one or the other, or both. However, the author intentionally used the same letter in both places, in order to indicate that the two variables "match up," so to speak.

Comment: what about the $m$ beside the congruence at the third line from below? are there 2 different m's?

Comment: @hopefully I've edited my post to respond.